# How to use existing kms key and subnet in aws cdk when deploying to multiple accounts

Tags: aws-cdk

I am have a aws cdk project creating stacks that are based on existing an existing kms key and existing subnet.

I need the subnet_id and the kms key arn for an IAM policy.

Since I did not find a way to find out the kms key arn and subnet id at runtime, I started by hardcoding them into the code.

But now I want to deploy the stack into different accounts (for which of the kms key arn and subnet id of course differs).

When I was using just Cloudformation, without aws cdk, I would use the `Mapping` section of the cloudformation template to map account ids to the needed information:

```
Mappings: 
  KMSKeyArn: 
    <account-id-1>: 
      ARN: <kms-key1-arn>
    <account-id-2>: 
      ARN: <kms-key2-arn>
```

What is a good way to do this with AWS CDK?
Should I use `CfnMapping`?

Or can I somehow know the Account ID at CDK Execution time?

Is there a better way I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

similar to the aws-cli, the cdk detects its account and region through the environment. See https://yshen4.github.io/infrastructure/AWS/CDK_context.html